# Adding flat html/css/js to drupal - not maintaining styling

Tags: drupal

I'm developing some JS animated components to add to a Drupal site. I typically work in JS and never Drupal, so the framework is where I'm having confusion. When I add the code into a WYSIWYG and preview, the components lose a lot of their styling - spacing, text color, font, etc. Is there anything Drupal specific that I need to ensure I do to make it so my components look the same when I view them locally vs on Drupal?

I've also heard about 'iframing'. Would this be an alternative that could fix this issue?

Comment: set the WYSIWYG to full html. It is probably set to basic html which will strip certain tags

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what version of Drupal you are using.

I would recommend to create a module to add this JS/CSS. 
Using the WYSIWYG to full html but having code, functionality into the Database can be a pain if your are having from dev environment and moving this then to production.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has so called "text formats" and default ones are "Filtered html", "Full html", "Plain text"...but you can also add custom ones.

When you edit some text with WYSIWYG editor just bellow that editor should be drop-down for selecting text format.

The thing is that each text format defines set of filters which will be applied when you save the content. So when you save content in i.e. "Filtered html" some html tags will be filtered out (removed / stripped) from your content and that can cause your code to fail.

Try using "Full html". Or even define your own text format (Configuration -> Contant authoring -> Text format in D7) and exclude all the filters that may destroy your code.

Alternative, if you don't need wysiwyg editor why don't you use plain text area instead?